# WP_QUERY, ARRAYS, Duplicate post if has multiple categories

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, shortcode

I have a shortcode with wp_query loop which outputs a list of categories as navigation and list of posts. The original code is much more complex so I tried to remove unnecessary lines for better understanding.

```
function filter_shortcode($atts, $content = null) {

    global $post;
    
    $attributes = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'type'      => '',  
            'num'       => -1
         ), $atts);

    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => $attributes["type"],
        'posts_per_page' => $attributes["num"]
    );  
        
    $post_query = new WP_Query($args);
    
    $master_array = array();
    
    if ($post_query->have_posts() ) {
            
        while ($post_query->have_posts()) {
                
            $post_query->the_post();
                    
            $nav_arr = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'solutions_category' );
            
            // Problem here
            foreach($nav_arr as $nav_value ) {
                $nav = $nav_value->name; 
            }
            
            
            $box_tooltip = '<div>Lorem Ipsum</div>';
            $info_box_title = '<h5 style="margin-bottom: 0;">' . strtoupper($post->post_title) . '</h5>';       
                
                
            if (!($master_array[$nav])) {
                $master_array[$nav] = array();
                array_push(
                      $master_array[$nav],
                      [ 
                        'icon_title'  => $info_box_title, 
                        'tooltip'     => $box_tooltip,  
                      ]
                );
            } else {
                array_push(
                      $master_array[$nav],
                      [ 
                        'icon_title'  => $info_box_title, 
                        'tooltip'     => $box_tooltip,  
                      ]
                );
            }
                
        } // End of while have_posts
        
        wp_reset_postdata();

        /* Foreach master array */
        foreach ((array)$master_array as $master_key => $master_value) {
            
            /* Navigation */
            $navigation .= '<div>'. $master_key .'</div>';

            foreach($master_value as $query_key => $query_value) {
                
                $output_inner = '';     
                
                foreach ($query_value as $object_key => $object_value) {
                    $output_inner .= $object_value;
                }
                /* Content */
                $output_outer .= '<div class="'. $master_key .'">'. $output_inner .'</div>';
                
            } // end foreach mastervalue

        } // end foreach master
    
    } // end if have posts
    
    return '
            <div style="margin-bottom: 30px;">'. $navigation .'</div>
            <div>'. $output_outer .'</div>
           ';
            
}
add_shortcode('cpt_filter', 'filter_shortcode');
```

Output:

[image]

The problem is that if post has more than one category the function will output only one occurrence of post. For example "GOOGLE WORKSPACE" has two categories - "Collaboration" and  "Communication" but it outputs only once.

[image]

**How I can output "GOOGLE WORKSPACE" as many times as the number of categories it has, and also to have it's own category class specified?**

**var_dump($nav_arr)** on "GOOGLE WORKSPACE" post iteration: `array(2) { [0]=> object(WP_Term)#3992 (10) { ["term_id"]=> int(825) ["name"]=> string(13) "Collaboration" ["slug"]=> string(13) "collaboration" ["term_group"]=> int(0) ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> int(825) ["taxonomy"]=> string(18) "solutions_category" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["parent"]=> int(0) ["count"]=> int(8) ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" } [1]=> object(WP_Term)#3986 (10) { ["term_id"]=> int(824) ["name"]=> string(13) "Communication" ["slug"]=> string(13) "communication" ["term_group"]=> int(0) ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> int(824) ["taxonomy"]=> string(18) "solutions_category" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["parent"]=> int(0) ["count"]=> int(8) ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" } }`

Tried to check if `$nav_arr` has more than one value `if (sizeof($nav_arr) > 1) { .... }` and create separate array, but stuck.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be that in the following foreach statement:

```
foreach($nav_arr as $nav_value ) {
    $nav = $nav_value->name; 
}
```

You are iterating through the array once, and setting the value of $nav to "Collaboration" and then when you are looping through it the second time, (because there are two items in $nav_arr), you are just rewriting $nav to the new value of "Communication", ending up with only one $nav.

$nav should be saved as an array of values, instead of a string of a single value, like this:

```
foreach($nav_arr as $nav_value){
    $nav[] = $nav_value;
}
```

Without seeing the full code, I am having a hard time understanding what all is going on.... but I think you can then **replace all of**:

```
if (!($master_array[$nav])) {
            $master_array[$nav] = array();
            array_push(
                  $master_array[$nav],
                  [ 
                    'icon_title'  => $info_box_title, 
                    'tooltip'     => $box_tooltip,  
                  ]
            );
        } else {
            array_push(
                  $master_array[$nav],
                  [ 
                    'icon_title'  => $info_box_title, 
                    'tooltip'     => $box_tooltip,  
                  ]
            );
        }
}
```

**with the following**:

```
foreach($nav as $navitem){
    $master_array[$nav] = array(
        'icon_title'  => $info_box_title,
        'tool_tip'    => $box_tooltip
    ),
}
```

Comment: Created an empty array before `foreach` loop so it will start with an empty array on each iteration - `$nav = [];` Now `var_dump($nav)` for "GOOGLE WORKSPACE"  is:  `array(2) { [0]=> string(13) "Collaboration" [1]=> string(13) "Communication" }` What should I change in `array_push`, `foreach ($master_array ...)`, `foreach($master_value ...)` and `foreach ($query_value ...)`?